Redacting third-party figure in journal article before including in thesis?
I have included a third-party figure (from a Springer subscription book) in an open-access Elsevier article (CC-BY 4.0 license). At the time, I obtained permission via RightsLink and included the acknowledgement (and copyright) statement in the figure caption, as required by the terms & conditions of the RightsLink license.
Now I want to include the published Elsevier article (i.e. in its final layout) in the appendix of my thesis. The thesis will be uploaded to an institutional repository. I learned that I am allowed to include the published CC-BY Elsevier article, but that I need to obtain permission from Springer again for the figure. However, when I try to obtain permission again via RightsLink (for reuse in dissertation/thesis), the terms & conditions now require an acknowledgement statement with slightly different wording. I am not sure if I should include a footnote with this new wording on the article page where the figure is located. I am a bit reluctant to ask Springer about this, because last time they took 6 weeks to reply to my email and I am running out of time.
TLDR: Is it OK to redact (=black out) the third-party figure in my published article before including it in my thesis, provided I put a footnote on the first page of the article (below the CC-BY license link), stating that the figure was blacked out due to third-party copyright and that the original article may be found at [ScienceDirect URL]?
According to CC-BY 4.0, I am free to:
"Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, even commercially. [...] You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made."
Does this mean that I may also alter a published article (in the journal's final layout) by blacking out a figure, as long as I make this very clear at the beginning of the article?
P.S.: My university staff would be fine with this solution. But my concern is, am I missing an important (legal) issue regarding the CC-BY license or maybe Elsevier?

Sorry, I don’t get why you want to include the article in your thesis in the first place. If it’s already published, why don’t you just reference it and that’s it? If you are willing to black out the figure, why not change the acknowledgment? It looks like you are fine with both citing and/or changing the article, both of which should trivially solve the problem if applied slightly differently.

According to my university's guidelines, simply referring to the articles is not enough, they must be included (and small changes are acceptable). Redacting the figure seemed like the easier solution, as I wouldn't have to contact Springer to clarify my outstanding issue regarding the acknowledgement of the figure. But I don't know if I'm allowed to change a fully layouted article, whether it's CC-BY 4.0 or not.

I think the PS that you have a workaround that your university staff OKs should suffice. I doubt anyone would target a published thesis for something like this. (That said, IANAL.)
